# Recovering Command-Shift-5 Screen Recordings on Mac

Tags: mac, data-recovery

I was recording for about 40 minutes today on my Macbook Air (Mojave) when my computer crashed. Is it possible for me to recover the file? There isn't a corrupted version or anything like that on my Desktop, where it would have gone had it finished properly. Please let me know if any other information would be helpful, or if this question could be better answered on another site.

EDIT: As mentioned, I couldn't even find a corrupted version of the recording on my Desktop. A specific question I have is where I might find such a thing.

Comment: hi, still no answer? i am looking for the same thing...